# Initializing a JavaBean

Tags: java, javabeans, initializer

I am finding myself making a lot of Classes for use in GUI building (hence they must conform to the JavaBean pattern). This has created some issues for me regarding initialising. I often have some method that is quite time intensive that must be executed once the state has been set.

One approach is to document that the method init() must be executed and hope that people read and respect it, but that is clumsy and means that the GUIBuilder can't just be used as intended, but rather extra code has to be added.

I've checked Bloch's "Effective Java", these forums and of course I asked Dr Google, but I haven't come up with anything. To be fair, it's a bit of a wishy-washy set of search terms.

The following short example (obviously trivialised) demonstrates my current approach. I have an "isInitialised" variable and invalidate the instance whenever a setter is called. Whenever a getter is called on a calculated variable (or any other complicated method), the isInitialised variable is checked and if needed the init() method is called.

```
public class BeanTest {

    private int someValue;          // Just some number
    private float anotherValue;     // Just another number
    private double calculatedValue; // Calculated by some expensive process

    private boolean isInitialised = false;  // Is calculatedValue valid?

    /**
     * Default constructor made available for JavaBean pattern
     */
    public BeanTest() {
        someValue = 0;
        anotherValue = 0;
    }

    //******* Getters and setters follow ************/
    public int getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }

    public void setSomeValue(int someValue) {
        if (someValue == this.someValue) {
            return;
        }        
        isInitialised = false;      // Calculated value is now invalid
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

    public float getAnotherValue() {
        return anotherValue;
    }

    public void setAnotherValue(float anotherValue) {
        if (anotherValue == this.anotherValue) {
            return;
        }
        isInitialised = false;      // Calculated value is now invalid
        this.anotherValue = anotherValue;
    }

    /**
     * This is where the time expensive stuff is done.
     */
    public void init() {
        if (isInitialised) {
            return;
        }

        /* In reality this is some very costly process that I don't want to run often,
         * probably run in another thread */
        calculatedValue = someValue * anotherValue;

        isInitialised = true;
    }

    /**
     * Only valid if initialised
     */
    public double getCalculatedValue() {

        init();

        return calculatedValue;
    }

    /**
     * Code for testing
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BeanTest myBean = new BeanTest();
        myBean.setSomeValue(3);
        myBean.setAnotherValue(2);
        System.out.println("Calculated value: " + myBean.getCalculatedValue());
    }
}
```

This approach has multiple issues. For example, it doesn't extend well (and some of these really are intended to be extended). Also, I show only a simple case here with three variables; the real classes have many more. Things are becoming a mess.

Can anybody suggest a different method or pattern that could help me keep the code more elegant and readable and still allow things to work as expected in a GUI builder please?

P.S.
This is meant to be mutable.

---

EDITED

I think by trivialising I hid the point a bit.

The trick is I want to run the init() stuff only once, and only when everything is set. If I was using a builder pattern, this would be easy, as I would put it in the build() method, but this is in a GUI element and so is in a JavaBean pattern.

The code I have above is a trivialised version of the "pattern" I am using. The pattern does work, but there are many weaknesses as I have noted, particularly with extensability (is that a word?) and as the number of variables grows. The trivial example looks alright, but the real code is starting to look horrendous.

I guess this could just be a weakness of the JavaBean pattern, but I thought I'd ask before I crafted another dozen dodgy classes in my package.

Comment: Since the class is mutable - are any previously calculated results invalidated immediately when a property changes, or do you have to set all of them again before a calculation can be performed again? In other words - do you always set all properties when the bean is updated?

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach: why not simply call init() in the setter instead?

A bit more fancy: use a [PropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) object. Sample usage:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class TestBean implements PropertyChangeListener{
    private int someValue;
    private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport;

    public TestBean() {
        changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }

    private void init() {
        //do something time consuming, maybe even on a different thread, using Futures?
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        init();
    }

    public int getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }

    public void setSomeValue(int someValue) {
        int oldValue = this.someValue;
        this.someValue = someValue;
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange("someValue", oldValue, someValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this leads to more calls to init() than strictly necessary. The calculations are time consuming, so this is not desirable.

Comment: You could keep track of whether you've `init`ed already and only call it once?

Comment: Is this a Swing GUI? It sounds like you might run into situations where the Event Dispatch Thread might block waiting for the calculations to complete using the calculate on getter-approach, leaving you with an unresponsive application.

Comment: Thanks Evan. That's essentially what I already am doing (see my code above). If there is a way of doing it without the problems regarding extensability and readability, then I guess that's what I'm after.

Comment: Vegard, you are completely correct. My trivialised version is perhaps over-trivialised; I actually perform the time critical stuff in another thread and call back to the function through a callback method. But yes, it is a Swing application.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have to accept that what I'm trying to achieve can't be done. Here is a quote from Bloch's "Effective Java":

> Unfortunately, the JavaBeans pattern has serious disadvantages of its
>   own. Because construction is split across multiple calls, a JavaBean
>   may be in an inconsistent state partway through its construction. The
>   class does not have the option of enforcing consistency merely by
>   checking the validity of the constructor parameters.

While it doesn't exactly answer my question, I think any answer that gets around the isInitialized variable would run into the issue that Bloch describes.